# Is there a way to use a fingerprint scanner with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air, fingerprint

I was curious if it's posible to integrate a fingerprint scanner to a Flash/Flex/AIR application, I can't seem to find anything on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe currently there's no way to directly connect to external devices using AIR, but if you use something like Merapi (http://www.merapiproject.net/), you could write a java api that would allow you to do a lot more.