# How to connect / communicate with fingerprint or scanner in flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, hardware, communication

I want to write application in adobe flex/air through which I can communicate/connect with hardware devices such as Fingerprint reader, scanner.

Is there any way to do so?

Is flex/air support hardware interaction with the following devices.

Comment: you can communicate with fingerprint reader with middle ware applications such as Java, .net etc. but i didn't know how to communicate with Air application

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500832/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-fingerprint-scanner-with-flex

Answer (score 3):

It's possible in AIR if you use [native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html).

You will have to write a separate native extension for each platform and compile separate application versions.

[Native extension example for Mac.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/hello-world-native-extensions-for-mac.html)

[Native extension example for Mac and Windows in C++.](http://www.flexjunk.com/2011/11/30/developing-an-air-native-extension-for-osx-and-windows-in-c/)